# Permanent solution for tik-tik noise in royal enfield bikes

Tags: engine, motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

I have a 2015 Royal Enfield Classic 350 UCE Twinspark

The bike is notorious for a valve ticking sound.

Is there any permanent solution for tik-tik noise for the Royal Enfield new model (UCE) engine bikes?

I have asked many Royal Enfield specialists and they are demanding huge amounts for fixing  noise.

Comment: Deafness?  Sell the bike?  I'm afraid we need a bit more to go on that simply tik-tik noise.  Have any of the mechanics stated what is causing the noise at all?

Comment: @SteveMatthews Every mechanic states different problem but one thing they tell same is that they need to open full engine which will cost me nearly $300.

Comment: To start with, please include the year/model/engine of your RE.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  model- classic 350 (2015) UCE twinspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In india, Since most of the mechanic are illiterate but has huge experience in the job, They dont know the technical name for a lot of problems in the motorcycles.

The 'Tik-Tik' noise is timing noise(Tappet noise) produced by the timing chain. Timing chains usually last about 30k - 50k kms and sometimes they last forever. If you experience timing chain problem I would suggest you to claim warranty from Royal Enfield for replacing tappet\timing chain and it's associated parts. The timing chain usually wont wear so quick so the timing adjuster may be faulted.

The assembling of the motorcycle engine is usually a automated process so I would doubt on a failure of the spare in first place. replace your timing adjuster since it doens't require opening the complete engine. If you still here noises, Then go for replacing the timing chain. If both of these options doesn't resolve the issue, then I would suggest you to check deep into hydraulic tappet parts.